# passing argument to shell function

Tags: makefile

I am new to Makefiles and was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
local-lint:
    poetry run sqlfluff fix $(shell find . -name "$${ARG}" -not -path "./target/*") --show-lint-violations
```

then:
`make local-lint ARG=myarg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but not quite the way you use it here, but why use `$(shell ...)`?  A recipe is already running in a shell, that's how make works (it invokes a shell to run the recipe).  So you don't need to use make's `shell` function inside a shell script... it just adds confusion (IMO).

The first problem you have is that when you want to expand a *make* variable, like the `ARG` variable, you do *not* want to escape it.  So your reference to `ARG` should just be `$(ARG)` or `${ARG}` (they are equivalent) not `$${ARG}`.

But a better way to write this is to avoid the `shell` function, as I mentioned; you can do it like this:

```
local-lint:
        poetry run sqlfluff fix `find . -name ${ARG} -not -path "./target/*"` --show-lint-violations
```

Or, if you prefer to use the newer shell syntax `$(...)` rather than backquotes you can but you need to escape the `$` because you want the shell to see this:

```
local-lint:
        poetry run sqlfluff fix $$(find . -name ${ARG} -not -path "./target/*") --show-lint-violations
```